# How to find record-value format of DLQ Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How to find record-value format of DLQ Topics.

I could see few dlq's are using json and few other dlq topics are using byte. Couldn't identify this in topics configuration also. Can anyone please provide reference document also if you have.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to possibly know this from seeing the topic name/config itself; you'll need to track down the source code that sets the serializer. If you use Confluent Schema Registry / Connect Converters, then there's a higher chance you could know, but querying it's API, but it's not a guarantee unless you also enforce server-side schema validation on the broker for those topics

But, all Kafka data can be consumed as byte array, so you could add a try-catch to test as String/JSON, and other formats.